# How to represent a fraction using javascript and query

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to represent fraction in a input box using jQuery I am not able to represent it the way it has to be represented! [I dont want it this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yizLC.png) ,  [I want it in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokOw.png) Right now I am using this `$("[purpose=fractionadd_imp_val]").val(improper[0]+" "+imp_num+"/"+imp_den);`

Comment: If you are planning to show it in input box, are you looking to even change it?

Comment: you can't do that because 5/6 isn't a single character in any font I know of

Comment: You could use a bit of CSS to style the numbers.

Comment: **inside** an input? @Nisarg

Comment: @JaromandaX hmm. Let's make it a contenteditable then.

Comment: Actually the input box will be disabled ! I think What I am asking is impossible ! I should either use css or some library !

Comment: It might be impossible if you want to edit it again. But yes if using css you can definitely achieve it. But the point is you will not be able to edit it easily

Comment: No there is no need of editing it !

Comment: It will be a final value !

Comment: Why not using for example Fraction.js ( https://github.com/infusion/Fraction.js ) in combination with KaTex ( https://katex.org/ ). The first parses a number and with its built-in function `Fraction(123).toTex()` you feed KaTex. Pretty good combination for what you're trying to achieve.